# Time series generation matlab

Tags: matlab, merge, time-series

I have an excel worksheet with several entries of column data. The data is arranged in pairs such that the first column contains dates and the second contains time series data corresponding to that date. So for example time series 1 will be in columns A and B where is is the dates and B is the data. Column C is blank before columns D and E contain the entries for time series 2 and so on and so forth...
How do I merge these into a single file in Matlab where the dates match up? Specifically I would want the first column to contain the dates and the other columns to contain the data. I have tried to do this with *fts* and *merge* functions but so far failed..

Comment: Are you reading the data in using `xlsread`? Can you should some code or describe your importing process?

Comment: yes, xlsread. I can import the whole worksheet using "[~,~,raw] = xlsread(fileName)"

Answer (score 0):

You could grab the dates like this: `dates = [raw{:,1}]'` and the data like this `data = reshape([raw{:, 2:3:end}]', size(raw,1), []);` to get normal matlab matrices in case you want to manipulate them in matlab.

Otherwise if you just want to send them straight back to excel then:

```
data = [raw(:,1) reshape(raw(:, 2:3:end)];
xlswrite(...blablafilename_etc..., data);
```

But in this case you should have use a VBA macro :/

Comment: Thanks @Dan. That's excellent. However does this match up the dates of the respective series? As the dates may not all correspond- this was my logic for using "merge".

Comment: @Mary what do you mean merge? Can you add the code you've tried to your question? No this won't work if the dates don't line up. If you have the stats toolbox you could use [datasets](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/datasetclass.html) and then use [join](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/dataset.join.html) for that... otherwise you could do it manually. But are you sure you need matlab for this?

Comment: Thanks. merge is in the financial toolbox. It automatically only includes data if all the time series contain data for that particular date. I have also the stats toolbox so I am welcome to suggestions from that also. unfortunately my code is more confusing than contributory.

Comment: Sounds appropriate, post your code and tell us where it goes wrong